# Getting SQL syntax error when I am trying to delete from multiple tables by joining

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I have to delete from couple of tables. These tables are fees, results, leaves and messages. All of them have a field called student_id. I want to delete from all these table rows whose student_id value is 3. But I am getting syntax error.

What am I doing wrong? Here is my query

```
delete from fees join results on fees.student_id = results.student_id join messages on results.student_id = messages.student_id join leaves on messages.student_id = leaves.student_id where fees.student_id = '3';
```

Comment: you cannot delete from multiple tables in one statement. You can join to as many tables as you need to get to the records that you must delete, but you need one `delete` per table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do four deletes?

```
delete from fees where student_id = 3;
delete from results where student_id = 3;
delete from leaves where student_id = 3;
delete from messages where student_id = 3;
```

You can do this in one query as:

```
delete f, r, l, m
  from fees f join
       results r
       on f.student_id = r.student_id join
       messages m
       on r.student_id = m.student_id join 
       leaves l
       on m.student_id = l.student_id
  where f.student_id = '3';
```

This runs the risk, though, that one of the tables will have no records for the students.  If the `join`s have no matches, nothing will be deleted.

Comment: that is a problem. If one of the table doesn't have a data I need to delete rows from other three tables. Is that possible?

Comment: @eddard.stark . . . Do the four separate deletes.